# Image Attachments Query Not Working If Post Is Loaded Via Ajax

Tags: images, ajax, attachments, gallery

Here's my problem: I'm trying to display a gallery of images attached to a post via ajax. The post is also loaded dynamically via ajax from the homepage. The query to retrieve the images however returns an empty array. The strange thing is, the **same query** actually works if the gallery is loaded via ajax, while the post is loaded "traditionally". To be more clear:

1st CASE:

1. I'm in INDEX.php
2. I load the post dynamically via ajax in INDEX.php
3. I launch the gallery dynamically via ajax from the post I've just loaded
4. The gallery DOES NOT work

2nd CASE:

1. I'm in SINGLE.php (meaning the post is loaded traditionally, not via ajax)
2. I launch the gallery dynamically via ajax
3. The gallery WORKS

Here's the query I'm using to retrieve the attaches images:

```
    // The post id I'm fetching from the AJAX call that loads the gallery
    $post_id = intval( $_POST['post_id'] );

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
        'order'=> 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_type' => 'attachment'
    );

    $images = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $images ) : 
          // Loop
    else : 
          // No posts
    endif;
```

And of course, unfortunately I get 'No posts' in the first case, while everything's fine in the second case... What's the difference?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe the post-id is not POSTed correctly? Did you try just displaying the post_id the script got?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me! There was an error in my AJAX call so I was passing the wrong post ID in the second case. So, nevermind guys.

(Is there a to delete a question? Can't seem to find one).